Problem 7.47 (Griffiths-Introduction to Electrodynamics)
I am trying to solve this problem from "Introduction to Electrodynamics" (Griffiths):
"A perfectly conducting spherical shell of radius $a$ rotates about the $z$ axis with angular velocity $\omega$, in a uniform magnetic field $B = B_0 \hat z$. Calculate the emf developed between the “north pole” and the equator."
The answer, according to Griffiths, should be $V=\frac{1}{2}B_0 \omega a^2$. However, I find that actually $V=0$, because the induced electric field is $E= v \times B$, where $v=\omega \times r=\omega \hat z \times r=\omega a\sin \varphi e_t $ (with $e_t$ I mean the tangential direction). Thus, the electric field should be:
$E=v \times B=\omega a \sin\varphi e_t \times B_0 \hat z= \omega a B_0 \sin \varphi \hat r$, that is $E$ is radial.
Now, the emf induced between the North Pole and the equator should be the integral of $E$ along a quarter of a maximum circle that connects the North Pole and the equator:
$V=\int_0^{\pi/2}E \cdot dr=0$ because $E$ and $dr$ are orthogonal to each other.
What am I missing??
Thanks for any help!

hint: $e_t \times \hat z \ne \hat r$ instead $e_t\times \hat \theta = \hat r$ where $\hat \theta$ is the unit vector pointing to the $z$ axis and is tangential to the NS great circle.

If $\textbf{E}=\omega aB_0\sin\phi\hat{\textbf{r}}$, then there is indeed a problem, and the resulting integral is $0$. The solution, then, must be that you have calculated the field wrong.
As hyportnex stated, $\hat{e}_t\times \hat{z}\neq\hat{r}$. To see why, recall that the cross product always produces a vector perpendicular to the two arguments. Since one of the arguments is $\hat{z}$, the result should not point at all in the $z$ direction. But as you move from the equator to the poles, $\hat{r}$ points more and more in the $z$ direction, and at the extremes (the poles), it is completely in the $z$ direction.
So the cross product cannot equal $\hat{r}$. Rather, the cross product should produce a vector that is parallel to the $xy$ plane everywhere and points out from the $z$ axis. If you compute the cross product correctly and recalculate the integral, you should see that everything works out.

Ok, I understand the mistake: this cross product should point outward from the surface and be always parallel to the $xy$ plane; but then it forms a variable angle with $dr$ in the integral. It is not parallel to it, right?

I'm assuming you mean $dr$ to be the differential of the path length along the surface of the sphere, or proportional to it, given how you set the boundaries in the integral in your question. I'll relabel it as $ds$ to avoid confusion with the radial variable $r$. In that case, $ds$ would not, in general, be parallel to the cross product. It would start parallel at the north pole of the sphere, but it would begin to point more and more vertically as you approach the equator, nearing a 90 degree angle with the cross product. Try drawing a picture to visualize this, and it'll help you solve it.

Yes, I mean the differential of the path. Thanks for your advice!

Motional EMF (due to motion in magnetic field) for a path $\gamma$ joining two points 1,2 is usually well given by
$$
\mathscr{E}  = \int_{\gamma} \mathbf v\times\mathbf B\cdot d\mathbf x.
$$
In general, it may depend on details of the path, however in this case, with uniform magnetic field, $\mathbf v\times\mathbf B$ turns out to be a field with components $\omega B_0(x,y,0)$, a conservative field, so only the endpoints matter, and details of the path do not.
In particular, we can use a path that has two parts: first goes straight from the pole to the sphere center (which contributes zero to the above integral), and then second goes from the center straight to the point on the equator.
Then we have
$$
\mathscr{E} =  \int_{\text{from center straight to surface}} \mathbf v\times\mathbf B \cdot d\mathbf x
$$
Using the components of $\mathbf v \times \mathbf B$ , and orienting the coordinate system so that the integration path goes along the axis $x$, we can express the integral as:
$$
\mathscr{E} =  \int_{0}^a \omega B_0 xdx = \frac{1}{2}\omega B_0 a^2.
$$
Note that in lab frame, this motional EMF is due to effect of magnetic field, not due to electric field. Electric field in the lab frame comes only from redistributed charge in the sphere, and actually opposes this EMF, so isolated rotating sphere will have zero radial current. To get this rotating sphere to drive radial current, the electric field has to be weakened, e.g. by some  non-rotating conductor that will bridge the pole and the point on the equator.
